# Unable to set focus in textfield in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uitextfield

Im new to objective-C and strucked at a point ..

I have created a View based application and placed tabbarController(drag and drop) onto mainwindow.xib...Since it is a ViewBasedApplication so my ViewController launches directly from AppDelegate.I have a UItextField in ViewController .. Now when the app launches I can see the UItextField ,TabBar with two tabbar items .But when I touch UItextField and try to enter some characters I couldnot see cursor on UITextField therby which I couldnot enter any
characters ..So I want UItextField to respond when I touch it..

How can I do it ?

Comment: Actually Im creating UItextField programatically..How can I assign delegate and to what should I set it ?

Answer (score 0):

App Delegate File:

```
 // Create instance of UINavigationController
    UINavigationController *myNavigationController;
    // Create initialized instance of UITabBarController
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    // Create initialized instance of NSMutableArray to hold our UINavigationControllers
    NSMutableArray *tabs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create first UIViewController
    UIViewController *myFirstViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [myFirstViewController setTitle:@"First"];
    // Initialize the UINavigationController
    myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myFirstViewController];
    // Add UINavigationController to you tabs
    [tabs addObject:myNavigationController];
    // Release UIViewController and UINavigationController
    [myFirstViewController release], [myNavigationController release];

    // Create second UIViewController
    UIViewController *mySecondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [mySecondViewController setTitle:@"Second"];
    // Initialize the UINavigationController
    myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mySecondViewController];
    // Add UINavigationController to you tabs
    [tabs addObject:myNavigationController];
    // Release UIViewController and UINavigationController
    [mySecondViewController release], [myNavigationController release];

    // Add the tabs to the UITabBarController
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:tabs];
    // Add the view of the UITabBarController to the window
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

## [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

ViewController.h file:

- In .h file

> UITextField *textfld;

- In .m file:

viewDidLoad method:

```
    textfld = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:<Frame>]; 
    textfld.delegate = self; 
    [textfld becameFirstResponder];
```

make your .h file textfielddelegate using

```
 @interface YourClassName:UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>.
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: No I dont want it on ViewLoad..When I touch textField then keyboard should appear and I should be able to enter data.But in my case when I try to keep cursor on textfield I couldnot see it Im unable to keep it also.It seems like it is locked(noneditable)..

Comment: Ohh.. Where are you adding your Tabbar in view?? Please add your view in tabbar & in window add tab bar as a rootview controller instead of tabbar. I think this is the base issue of your code.

Comment: If Possible, Please provide the code in your appdidfinishlaunching method of App delegate class. Also please follow this tutorial: http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2009/01/24/creating-uitabbarcontroller-based-app-using-interfacebuilder.html

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];  
    
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
   [self.window addSubview:[self.tabBarController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

Comment: That is my  appdidfinishlaunching method of App delegate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18619/discussion-between-icreative-and-arizah)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
[textfld setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```